# Refresh Grant type

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I was trying the 3Leg Oath process but during the code exchange process in second step i am getting a 401 Error, I rechecked my Client id it was correct.
Could someone help me with the process.

Thanks

[the code should return the access token and refresh token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5WAu.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.